# ERROR: source_sink `' /Users...'' does not exist (Cannot compile prolog file)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I entered

```
?- [' /Users/Alexis/Desktop/A10.pl ']
```

on the SWI Prolog REPL, and the following errors occurred:

```
    ERROR: source_sink `' /Users/Alexis/Desktop/A10.pl '' does not exist
    ERROR: In:
    ERROR:   [20] throw(error(existence_error(source_sink,' /Users/Alex/Desktop/A10.pl '),_4920))
    ERROR:   [15] '$load_file'(' /Users/Alexis/Desktop/A10.pl ',user,[expand(false),...]) at /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/init.pl:1951
    ERROR:    [7] <user>
    ERROR: 
    ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
    ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

what's more, no matter what `.pl` file I enter , the same errors above appear. The directory of `.pl` file is right but it just cannot be compiled. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the spaces around the path.

`?- [' /Users/Alexis/Desktop/A10.pl ']` will fail with that error.

`?- ['/Users/Alexis/Desktop/A10.pl']` should not.

Comment: Ahhhh okay. Thank U!! :)